# setZoomScale: and zoomToRect: works on device but it doesn't on iOS Simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, ios-simulator

I have a UIScrollView wich does provide zooming function with pinch gestures,it's controller is conform to UIViewScrollDelegate, implement it's methods and everything...
This works perfectly fine on my iOS device,it scrolls and zoom in/out.
When it comes to try it on the simulator, it just wont work(the two gray-circles pop out when i press the option key though).

Since it works fine on my device, is not a big deal ... but I need it to works on iOS simulator too, because I would like to make a video out of it. What could be the possible problems?

Additional info:

- UIScrollView is the main view of the controller mentioned above
- UIScrollView is created in the XIB file
- it have a subview
- I've tried it on every version/device of the iOS simulator(iPad,iPhone,Retina)
- **Even zoomToRect works fine on device but not on the simulator**

Comment: Are you saying that it doesn't work without pressing alt? Or are you saying that it doesn't work after pressing alt?

Comment: I'am using a XIB wich have just the UIScrollView. The subview is created and added programmatically. It doesn't work, even if the two gray-dots appear when I press alt.

Comment: Press option button and left click mouse button to scale your pinch. It should work for you.

Comment: Yes, this is what i'm doing. Is not working.